# BigQuery remove <0x00> hidden characters from a column

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table with unwanted hidden characters such as `my_table`:

| id | fruits |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | STuff1 stuff_2 ���������������������� |
| 2 | Blahblah-blahblah ������������� |
| 3 | nothing |

How do I remove `����������������������` when selecting this column?

Current query:

```
SELECT fruits, TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(fruits, r'[^a-zA-Z,0-9,-]', ' ')) AS new_fruits
FROM `project-id.MYDATASET.my_table`
```

This query is too flaw because I'm worried if I accidentally exclude/replace important data. I only want to be specific on this weird characters.

Upon opening the data as csv, the weird characters shows as `<0x00>`. How do I solve this?

Comment: The characters are not hidden. Most likely you have mixed Ascii and Unicode. The funny question marks mean that your display device does not know how to display those characters. Debug those characters to determine the correct format/codepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to identify which is this character, because as it is a non printable this sign is just a random representation. For replace it without remove any other important information, do the following:

- identify the hexadecimal of the character. Copy from csv and past on this [site](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html):
  [image]
- Use the replace function in bigquery replacing the char of this hex, as following:

```
SELECT trim(replace(string_field_1,chr(0xfffd)," ")) FROM `<project>.<dataset>.<table>`;
```

[image]

**if your character result is different than fffd, put you value on the chr() function**